# Cant connect to MS Access mdb file using DBeaver and the default UCanAccess-5.0.0 driver

Tags: ms-access, dbeaver, ucanaccess

Get the following error:
UCAExc:::5.0.0-SNAPSHOT unexpected token: DOUBLE required: FOR
unexpected token: DOUBLE required: FOR

My connection string is:
jdbc:ucanaccess:///mnt/toolboss-plt11/sps.mdb
everything else contains default values.
I believe the mdb file is in Access 2000 format.  I am able to connect to this file with Microsoft SSIS jet 4.0 driver.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a download link for a sample .mdb file that can be use to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thank you, Gord.  It is a work database so I can't.  Are you able to connect to any Access 2000 type mdb files with DBeaver?

Comment: Yes, [I can](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVVXM.png). Do you get the error when you first try to open the database, or only when you try to work with a particular table or view?

Comment: Thank you, Gord. Can you please show me your [connection string](https://ibb.co/31mNPQM) and [driver settings](https://ibb.co/gmQ0sjS).

Comment: My settings are straight out-of-the-box defaults for the current version of DBeaver: [connection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INjaw.png) and [driver properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLvlf.png).

Comment: Thank you again, Gord.  Would you be willing to share that mdb file?

Comment: Much appreciated, Gord. Your file works. Can you please try to connect to one of my databases? https://www.dropbox.com/s/scksrioo6kntk93/test.mdb?dl=0

Answer (score 4):

You have encountered a bug in UCanAccess/HSQLDB. When I try to open your test file using UCanAccess' `console.bat` I see

```
C:\Users\Public\Downloads\UCanAccess>console.bat
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)

Please, enter the full path to the access file (.mdb or .accdb): /home/gord/Desktop/test.mdb
Cannot execute:CREATE  CACHED TABLE RATIONING(ITEMTYPE INTEGER,ITEMKEY VARCHAR(50),ISSUETARGETTYPE INTEGER,ISSUETARGETKEY VARCHAR(50),MAXQTY INTEGER,PERIOD DOUBLE,PERIODTYPE INTEGER) unexpected token:
 DOUBLE required: FOR
```

It appears that `PERIOD` is a reserved word in HSQLDB 2.5.0 (the version that ships with UCanAccess 5.0.x). However after upgrading to HSQLDB 2.5.1 that same CREATE statement doesn't fail.

You should post a [help request](https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/) on SourceForge asking Marco to update the version of HSQLDB in the UCanAccess distribution. In the meantime you can work around the issue.

Download [UCanAccess-5.0.1.bin.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/files/latest/download) and unpack it. I put my copy in "/home/gord/Downloads/JDBC/"

[image: uca1]

Go into the "lib" folder and delete "hsqldb-2.5.0.jar". Download [hsqldb-2.5.1.jar](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.5.1/hsqldb-2.5.1.jar) to replace it.

[image: uca2]

In DBeaver, right-click your connection and choose "Edit Connection". Click the "Edit Driver Settings" button and in the Libraries tab delete the "net.sf.ucanaccess.ucanaccess:RELEASE" entry that DBeaver created. Then use the "Add File" button to add the five (5) jars from your download folder

[image: jars]

Now you should be able to open your .mdb file.

Comment: Thank you, Gord. Your help is greatly appreciated!  And I did fill out a help request to Marco.