# UCanAccess connection error UCAExc:::5.0.1

Tags: ucanaccess

I'm trying to connect to the MS Access database (.mdb) using UCanAccess and the connection error with the message below

```
Failed to validate account: Failed to retrieve a database connection. Cause: UCAExc:::5.0.1 unexpected token: VARCHAR required: FOR (Reason: UCAExc:::5.0.1 unexpected token: VARCHAR required: FOR; Resolution: Address the reported issue.)
```

but when I tried to connect to other .mdb on the same path, the connection success

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved. It's hsqldb-2.5.0 bug as someone replied in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66121983/9023405